# RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [32, 1] at entry 0 and [32, 0] at entry 1

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, tensor

I have a very large tensor of shape `(512,3,224,224)`. I input it to model in batches of 32 and I then save the scores corresponding to the target label which is `2`. in each iteration, after every slice, the shape of `scores` changes. Which leads to the following error. What am I doing wrong and how to fix it.
`label = torch.ones(1)*2`

```
def sub_forward(self, x):
    x = self.vgg16(x)
    x = self.bn1(x)
    x = self.linear1(x)
    x = self.linear2(x)
    return x
```

```
def get_scores(self, imgs, targets):
    b, _, _, _ = imgs.shape
    batch_size = 32
    total_scores = []
    for i in range(0, b, batch_size):
      scores = self.sub_forward(imgs[i:i+batch_size,:,:,:])
      scores = F.softmax(scores)
      labels = targets[i:i+batch_size]
      labels = labels.long()
      scores = scores[:,labels]
      print(i," scores: ", scores)
      total_scores.append(scores)
      print(i," total_socres: ", total_scores)
    total_scores = torch.stack(total_scores)
    return scores
```

```
0  scores:  tensor([[0.0811],
        [0.0918],
        [0.0716],
        [0.1680],
        [0.1689],
        [0.1319],
        [0.1556],
        [0.2966],
        [0.0913],
        [0.1238],
        [0.1480],
        [0.1215],
        [0.2524],
        [0.1283],
        [0.1603],
        [0.1282],
        [0.2668],
        [0.1146],
        [0.2043],
        [0.2475],
        [0.0865],
        [0.1869],
        [0.0860],
        [0.1979],
        [0.1677],
        [0.1983],
        [0.2623],
        [0.1975],
        [0.1894],
        [0.3299],
        [0.1970],
        [0.1094]], device='cuda:0')
0  total_socres:  [tensor([[0.0811],
        [0.0918],
        [0.0716],
        [0.1680],
        [0.1689],
        [0.1319],
        [0.1556],
        [0.2966],
        [0.0913],
        [0.1238],
        [0.1480],
        [0.1215],
        [0.2524],
        [0.1283],
        [0.1603],
        [0.1282],
        [0.2668],
        [0.1146],
        [0.2043],
        [0.2475],
        [0.0865],
        [0.1869],
        [0.0860],
        [0.1979],
        [0.1677],
        [0.1983],
        [0.2623],
        [0.1975],
        [0.1894],
        [0.3299],
        [0.1970],
        [0.1094]], device='cuda:0')]
32  scores:  tensor([], device='cuda:0', size=(32, 0))
32  total_socres:  [tensor([[0.0811],
        [0.0918],
        [0.0716],
        [0.1680],
        [0.1689],
        [0.1319],
        [0.1556],
        [0.2966],
        [0.0913],
        [0.1238],
        [0.1480],
        [0.1215],
        [0.2524],
        [0.1283],
        [0.1603],
        [0.1282],
        [0.2668],
        [0.1146],
        [0.2043],
        [0.2475],
        [0.0865],
        [0.1869],
        [0.0860],
        [0.1979],
        [0.1677],
        [0.1983],
        [0.2623],
        [0.1975],
        [0.1894],
        [0.3299],
        [0.1970],
        [0.1094]], device='cuda:0'), tensor([], device='cuda:0', size=(32, 0))]
```

```
> RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [32, 1] at entry 0 and [32, 0] at entry 1
```

Comment: Please improve your question by following Stackoverflow guideline https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what happen to your code but you shouldn't do the batching like that honestly. Please use Dataset:

```
import torch

class MyDataloader(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self):
        self.images = torch.Tensor(512, 3, 224, 224)

    def __len__(self):
        return 512

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.images[idx, :, :, :], torch.ones(1) * 2

train_data = MyDataloader()
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_data,
                                           shuffle=True,
                                           num_workers=2,
                                           batch_size=32)
for batch_images, targets in train_loader:
    print(batch_images.shape)  # should be 32*3*224*224

    ... # let train your model
    logits = model(batch_images, targets)
```

Comment: Why not? can u tell me why is this a bad practice?

Comment: shuffle, preload data in CPU concurrently while use GPU to train and OOP.

Comment: I can not use shuffle, as I am going to use the input tensor and output of the model in sequence to do some computations later

Comment: can u give me any suggestions on my other recent post

Comment: @UmairJavaid Sorry I was AFK for a while. Did you solve that?